# Plpgsql function multiple inserts

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have a plpgsql function `insert_all` that calls `insert` function in a loop to insert 10.000 records from `source` table to `dest`. This takes about 2 minutes. I would like to optimize.

```
create table source(a text, b text, c text);
create table dest(a text, b text);

create or replace function insert(p1 text, p2 text)
returns void as $$
begin
insert into dest values (p1, p2);
end
$$ language plpgsql;

create or replace function insert_all()
returns void as $$
declare r record;
begin
for r in (select * from source) loop
    perform insert(r.a, r.b);
end loop;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I think `insert into dest (select a, b from source)` should be faster but calling `insert` function in a loop is preferred because it is called from let say 10 different places in code and every change influences this 10 places.

I ask for an advice how to optimize inserting, my tables and functions are more complex but the principle is the same.

Comment: The principle is indeed the same. You have a RDBMS at your disposal. Don't loop - do INSERT ... SELECT instead. Nothing in your example shows why you can't/shouldn't do that.

Comment: I don't understand the usage of a loop in this case. A simple INSERT ... SELECT (like @RichardHuxton already mentioned) is much simpler and faster. Advice: Start thinking in sets of data instead of thinking in single records.

Comment: "*I would like to optimize*" - get rid of the functions and slow loops and use a single INSERT ... SELECT statement.

Comment: Insert ... select will be orders of magnitude faster runtime than "loop to call function,  insert". OK you have 10 places! Make sure it is properly documented and write the "Insert ... select" in each location assuming of course the source is different in each.  The question becomes what are you trying to optimize run time or developer time.